Why does my code crash when I call TTGetEmbeddedFontInfo?
My goal is to obtain the filename of the font selected in an HDC without using DirectWrite.
To do so, I thought I could use TTGetEmbeddedFontInfo() because the doc says:

Pointer to a TTLOADINFO structure containing the URL from which the embedded font object has been obtained.

But, currently, when I call TTGetEmbeddedFontInfo(), my program crashes. It is probably related to my read_proc function, which is a READEMBEDPROC, but I can't find why it happens.
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <t2embapi.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "t2embed.lib")


unsigned long CALLBACK write_proc(void* tFile, const void* buffer,
    const unsigned long count)
{
    std::wcout << L"write_proc is called" << std::endl;

    return (unsigned long)fwrite((char*)buffer, 1, count, (FILE*)tFile);
}

unsigned long CALLBACK read_proc(void* tFile, void* buffer,
    const unsigned long count)
{
    std::wcout << L"read_proc is called" << std::endl;

    return (unsigned long)fread((char*)buffer, 1, count, (FILE*)tFile);
}


int main()
{

    HDC hdc = CreateCompatibleDC(nullptr);
    if (hdc == nullptr)
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to call CreateCompatibleDC");

    WCHAR tempPath[MAX_PATH];
    WCHAR tempFileName[MAX_PATH];
    UINT uRetVal;

    if (GetTempPathW(MAX_PATH, tempPath) == 0)
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to call GetTempPathW");

    if (GetTempFileNameW(tempPath, L"TMP", 0, tempFileName) == 0)
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to call GetTempFileNameW");

    std::wcout << L"tempFileName: " << tempFileName << std::endl;

    FILE* tfile = _wfopen(tempFileName, L"wb+");
    if (tfile == NULL)
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to call fopen");

    LOGFONTW lf{};
    lf.lfCharSet = DEFAULT_CHARSET;
    wcscpy_s(lf.lfFaceName, L"Arial");
    lf.lfItalic = false;
    lf.lfWeight = 400;
    lf.lfOutPrecision = OUT_TT_PRECIS;
    lf.lfClipPrecision = CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS;
    lf.lfQuality = ANTIALIASED_QUALITY;
    lf.lfPitchAndFamily = DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_DONTCARE;

    HFONT hfont = CreateFontIndirectW(&lf);
    if (hfont == NULL)
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to call CreateFont");

    SelectObject(hdc, hfont);

    ULONG ulFlags = TTEMBED_RAW;
    ULONG ulCharSet = CHARSET_UNICODE;
    ULONG ulPrivStatus;
    ULONG ulStatus;
    if (TTEmbedFontEx(hdc, ulFlags, ulCharSet, &ulPrivStatus, &ulStatus, (WRITEEMBEDPROC) write_proc, tfile, 0, 0, 0, nullptr) != E_NONE)
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to call TTEmbedFontEx. error code: " + ulStatus);

    fseek(tfile, 0, SEEK_SET);

    std::wcout << L"The next call is TTGetEmbeddedFontInfo which currently fails" << std::endl;

    TTLOADINFO loadInfo = { 0 };
    loadInfo.usStructSize = sizeof(TTLOADINFO);
    if (TTGetEmbeddedFontInfo(ulFlags, &ulPrivStatus, LICENSE_DEFAULT, &ulStatus, (READEMBEDPROC) read_proc, tfile, &loadInfo) != E_NONE)
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to call TTGetEmbeddedFontInfo. error code: " + ulStatus);

    std::wcout << L"ulPrivStatus: " << ulPrivStatus << std::endl;
    std::wcout << L"ulStatus: " << ulStatus << std::endl;
    std::wcout << L"Filename size: " << loadInfo.usRefStrSize << std::endl;
    if (loadInfo.pusRefStr == nullptr) {
        std::wcout << L"Filename: is null" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::wcout << L"Filename: " << (wchar_t*)loadInfo.pusRefStr << std::endl;
    }


    fclose(tfile);
    DeleteObject(hfont);
    DeleteDC(hdc);

    return 0;
}


Are you compiling this code for 32bit or 64bit? Your callbacks are both missing the WINAPIV (aka __stdcall) calling convention, which will cause undefined behavior under 32bit.

I'm compiling for 64 bits, but I want my code to also work under 32 bits

Another issue I see is after TTEmbedFontEx()is done writing to the FILE*, you are not seeking it back to the beginning of the file, so TTGetEmbeddedFontInfo() will try to read from the end of the file and fail since there is nothing to rear.

Good catch! I edited my code based on your suggestion, but my program still crashes

"Pointer to a TTLOADINFO structure containing the URL from which the embedded font object has been obtained." It doesn't appear that your TTLOADINFO structure contains an URL.

@RaymondChen so, does that mean that for TTGetEmbeddedFontInfo(), the TTLOADINFO needs a pre-allocated buffer to write the URL into? Or does the URL need to be provided as input for TTGetEmbeddedFontInfo()? The doc does not make this clear

@RaymondChen You're right that I haven't passed a pTTEmbedInfo to TTEmbedFontEx, but since the phrasing isn't clear, I thought it might be able to resolve the URL

@RemyLebeau I thought it was clear. It says "containing the URL" not "which receives the URL". You are expected to pass the URL in.
